# Access static variables in an abstract class in PHP

Tags: php

Is there any other way to access a static variable from a static method, other than using classname::$variable?

Comment: Why do you want to access it other way?

Comment: I've created a wrapper for a few functions (in the form of a class), and I want to set the variables i would need in all the methods in a static variable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`self::$variable`, if it's in the same class.

Answer (score 1):

If it is different class:

```
classname::$variable
```

If it is same class:

```
self::$variable
```